# Is is possible to select clang for compiling CPython extensions on Linux?

Tags: clang, cpython

All's in the title: I'd like to try using clang for compiling a C extension module for CPython on Linux (CPython comes from the distro repositories, and is built with gcc).

1. Do distutils/setuptools support this?
2. Does the fact that CPython and the extension are built with two different compilers matter?

Thanks.

Comment: there is a environment variable for that, just cant recall its name.

Comment: try CC=clang python setup.py build

Comment: Works, thanks.  Feel free to make this a response so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a environment variable for that.

   CC=clang python setup.py build
2. Both of compiled binaries are compatible with CPython